How to display an object from server side to client side as a chart using express+ejs+chartjs?
I am trying to pass two objects weights(list with integer value) and progressDatas(list with string value) from the server side to the client side. In the client side I am stuck at how to render the the list data to the chart value as mentioned below
Server side:
res.render("viewProgress.ejs",{weights:weights,progressDatas:progressDatas});

Client side:
<body>
   <canvas id="progressChart"></canvas>
   <script>
     const ctx = document.getElementById('progressChart').getContext('2d');
     const tempChart = new Chart(ctx, {
       type: 'bar',
       data: {
         labels: { pdatas }, // How to correctly render pdatas?
         datasets: [{
           label: 'weight',
           data: { weightData }, // How to correctly render weightData?
           backgroundColor: ['#A5DD9B'],
           borderColor: ['#416D19'],
           borderWidth: 1,
         }]
       },
       options: {
         scales: {
           y: {
             beginAtZero: true
           }
         }
       }
     });
   </script>
</body>


I am stuck at this part
Thanks for any advice

From the examples on the official docs, I see that they pass the whole canvas element and not just the context to the Chart constructor. Furthermore, the data is passed as an array, so I think you should remove the curled brackets around the variables, assuming they are in fact arrays.

@greenSaiko I tried it but not able to see the chart on the client side

To correctly render the pdatas and weightData in your client-side JavaScript, you should pass them as arrays from your server-side and then iterate over them in your client-side script to format them correctly for the chart. Here's how you can modify your client-side code to achieve this:
 Server side:

    res.render("viewProgress.ejs",{weights:weights,progressDatas:progressDatas}); 


    Client side:

   <body>
   <canvas id="progressChart"></canvas>
   <script>
     const ctx = document.getElementById('progressChart').getContext('2d');

     // Assuming pdatas and weightData are arrays passed from the server
     const pdatas = <%= JSON.stringify(progressDatas) %>;
     const weightData = <%= JSON.stringify(weights) %>;

     const tempChart = new Chart(ctx, {
       type: 'bar',
       data: {
         labels: pdatas, // Use pdatas directly as it's already an array
         datasets: [{
           label: 'weight',
           data: weightData, // Use weightData directly as it's already an array
           backgroundColor: ['#A5DD9B'],
           borderColor: ['#416D19'],
           borderWidth: 1,
         }]
       },
       options: {
         scales: {
           y: {
             beginAtZero: true
           }
         }
       }
     });
   </script>
</body>


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
